# Command Button enable and disable

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

Synopsis : 
     I Have check box tableviewer in my view. i want command button in view toolbar and popmenu of the view should be enabled/ visible in popupmenu  when user has checked any row (Checked rows > 0)in the table viewer else (Checked rows < 0)the command button should be disable  in toolbar and in visible in popup menu.....
can any one tell how implement this ?????

Thanks
Ashok

Answer (score 3):

you can disable a command programmatically with variables.
on the command contribution define the "enableWhen".
see [Command Expressions](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/workbench_cmd_expressions.htm)

to define your own variables, you have to use the org.eclipse.ui.services extension point and define a SourceProvider. You can find many examples of such providers.
see [this blog post](http://www.eclipse-tips.com/tutorials/1-actions-vs-commands?start=3) for an example

good luck!